# Tailwindcss layout like github personal dashboard

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm having trouble with tailwindcss grid layout. I want a page with 3 columns. Column 1 or sidebarleft should occupy 10-15% of screen. Column 2 or main content should occupy 70-80% of screen. and column 3 or sidebar right should occupy 10-15% of screen as well. How can I achieve this with tailwindcss?

I have the following; column 3 should be a child of column 3 I think.

```html
<div className="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-1 h-screen gap-2 grid-flow-col">
  <div className="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center">Sidebar left</div>
  <div className="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center col-span-2">Main content</div>
  <div className="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center">side bar right</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the number of columns in your `grid` to 10, then give each `div` a `col-span-x` depending on the width you want:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-10 grid-rows-1 h-screen gap-2 grid-flow-col">
  <div class="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center col-span-1">Sidebar left</div>
  <div class="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center col-span-8">Main content</div>
  <div class="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center col-span-1">side bar right</div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jvm3pWMF2s)

---

Because you want your width to be more dynamic, I wouldn't use `grid` here but `flex`.
This way, you can easily control the minimum and maximum width of each `div`.

```html
<div class="flex gap-2 h-screen">
  <div class="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center min-w-[10%] max-w-[15%]">Sidebar left</div>
  <div class="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center grow">Main content</div>
  <div class="bg-green-100 text-green-500 text-lg font-bold text-center min-w-[10%] max-w-[15%]">side bar right</div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Uh2xqHVMsr)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `grid-cols-*` and `grid-rows-*` properties in the parent div and use `col-span-*` in the child. (Note: Here, * means number). You get clear idea from example.
[see here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/hYqwgTj5zh)